# Recording events(request & response) in an MVC application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Ok, so I have quite a task here:

The background of this project is very complex and fully covered by NDA's so I'll just state what I am trying to do without the background.

So what I need is a way to record every request made to an MVC application and every response from it.

Furthermore, I also need a way to "reply" the requests exactly as they were sent.

I was hoping that I could create some solution that "loads" the MVC application, Self hosts or runs in IIS, get requests, records them and passed them verbatim to the MVC application which would then act exactly like any other MVC app.

I could then create a second solution that "loads" the MVC app but instead of opening it up to request it would read the events from the event store and "replays" them in the MVC app.

Now I have no clue where to even start.  This kinda thing is *way* out of my comfort zone.

If there is another solution for how I can record and replay request (and responses) then please let me know.

Even if there is a way to intercept a request in MVC before it starts doing all of its authentication and routing malarkey then that would be a great starting point.  I would also need to know where I can capture the response at the very last second before it is sent.

Many thanks for your time
Andy

Comment: Sounds like some sort of webserver log might accomplish parts of this

Answer (score 0):

A `HttpModule` would work just fine for your scenario:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public class HelloWorldModule : IHttpModule
{
   public HelloWorldModule()
   {
   }

   public String ModuleName
   {
       get { return "HelloWorldModule"; }
   }

   // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
   // events by adding your handlers.
   public void Init(HttpApplication application)
   {
      application.BeginRequest += 
          (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
      application.EndRequest += 
          (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
   }
   private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, 
        EventArgs e)
   {
      // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
      // request and response properties.
      HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
      HttpContext context = application.Context;  
      /*...*/      
   }

   private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
   {
      HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
      HttpContext context = application.Context;
      /*...*/
   }

   public void Dispose() { }
}
```

The code and more information available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx).